# Why does a sphere not have a boundary

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

Let S be a geometric surface.
**Definition**: [Boundary of a surface] A surface with a boundary is a surface along with boundary points. A boundary point $P$ is a point such that there exists an open set $U$ in $R^3$ so that $P ∈ U ∩ S$ is homeomorphic to a half disk in. The set of all boundary points is called the boundary of $S$ and is denoted by $∂S$. Caution: Boundary of a subset of $R^3$ is not the same as the boundary of a surface in $R^3$.

This is the definition of the boundary of a surface. I am having trouble understanding why a sphere, or a torus doesn't have a boundary, according to the definition. Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You may want to clarify your definitions. Your sentences  currently suggest that a point $P$ is  homeomorphic to something (I would assume you really want a *set* to be homeomorphic to something, not a *point*). You also end a sentence by "..to a half disk in." That seems incomplete. It may also help to more gracefully introduce the object $S$ (currently, $S$ suddenly appears and we do not know what it represents). It may be easier to keep things clear if you use small-case $p$ for points and large-case $U,S$ for sets.

Comment: Do you know why there is no homeomorphism of the half disk taking an interior point to a boundary point?